# Rename SSH Key Agent that was already added

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd, ssh-keys

I added 2 ssh key using `ssh-keygen` command, one for personal and one for client. Running `ssh-add -l` will display all the agent added via `ssh-add` and this is what I get.

[image]

I wonder if we can rename the existing ssh key email so it is much clearer. As much as possible I do not want to delete the existing, just want to update its email.

I didn't know before that you can configure ssh key generation like this

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "personal@email.com" -f id_rsa
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "client@email.com" -f id_rsa-client
```

Which could give me a list of ssh agent with different email when running `ssh-add -l`

```
4096 SHA256:XXXXXX personal@email.com (RSA)
4096 SHA256:XXXXXX client@email.com (RSA)
```

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl isn't this consider under `software tools commonly used by programmers`? I need to understand SSH so I can access a repository, I don't understand the big deal about it?

Comment: Yes, but it's not *"unique to software development"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't actually emails, just "comments". You can update the keyfile with

```
ssh-keygen -c -C "personal@email.com" -f .ssh\id_rsa
```

Then remove and re-add the identity with (WARNING: The command below will delete ALL keys)

```
ssh-add -D
ssh-add
```

Your key would still work with the sites and servers you've registered the public key to.

Comment: Do I still need to update the SSH key as well in the repository?

Comment: They'll still work without updating. If you want to update their name as well, just paste the public key with the comment changed.

Comment: Thanks it works, I thought ssh-keygen will always create new ssh key or overwrite completely the old one

Comment: That command just deleted all keys from my agent.. not just that single keyfile. A warning would have been nice.